Not able to get the header on sonos
I am integrating my service on sonos
looking for the below design to achieve

<?xml version="1.0"?>
                <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
                    <soap:Body>
                        <ns:getMetadataResponse>
                            <ns:getMetadataResult>
                                <ns:index>0</ns:index>
                                <ns:count>8</ns:count>
                                <ns:total>8</ns:total> 

                                <ns:mediaMetadata>
                                    <ns:id>f2</ns:id>
                                    <ns:title>Smooth 80s</ns:title>
                                    <ns:mimeType>application/vnd.apple.mpegurl</ns:mimeType>
                                    <ns:itemType>stream</ns:itemType>
                                    <ns:summary>all your 80s favourites</ns:summary>
                                    <ns:streamMetadata>
                                        <ns:
                                    </ns:streamMetadata>
                                </ns:mediaMetadata>
                                <ns:mediaMetadata>
                                    <ns:id>b06f7381-0da5-4a22-bf2c-c9e1297615b3</ns:id>
                                    <ns:title>Smooth Relax</ns:title>
                                    <ns:mimeType>application/vnd.apple.mpegurl</ns:mimeType>
                                    <ns:itemType>stream</ns:itemType>
                                    <ns:summary>your easy place to relax</ns:summary>
                                    <ns:streamMetadata>
                                        <ns:
                                    </ns:streamMetadata>
                                </ns:mediaMetadata>
                                <ns:mediaMetadata>
                                    <ns:id>28</ns:id>
                                    <ns:title>Smooth Vintage</ns:title>
                                    <ns:mimeType>application/vnd.apple.mpegurl</ns:mimeType>
                                    <ns:itemType>stream</ns:itemType>
                                    <ns:summary>non-stop classics</ns:summary>
                                    <ns:streamMetadata>
                                        <ns:
                                    </ns:streamMetadata>
                                </ns:mediaMetadata>
                                <ns:mediaMetadata>
                                    <ns:id>0980474c-e922-45ad-b6c2-c8f2d9b3bd81</ns:id>
                                    <ns:title>Smooth FM 95.3</ns:title>
                                    <ns:mimeType>application/vnd.apple.mpegurl</ns:mimeType>
                                    <ns:itemType>stream</ns:itemType>
                                    <ns:summary>Sydney's station for more music and less talk</ns:summary>
                                    <ns:streamMetadata>
                                        <ns:
                                    </ns:streamMetadata>
                                </ns:mediaMetadata>
                                <ns:mediaMetadata>
                                    <ns:id>b903582a-3e0a-4b37-be07-43d439821259</ns:id>
                                    <ns:title>Smooth FM 91.5</ns:title>
                                    <ns:mimeType>application/vnd.apple.mpegurl</ns:mimeType>
                                    <ns:itemType>stream</ns:itemType>
                                    <ns:summary>Melbourne's station for more music and less talk</ns:summary>
                                    <ns:streamMetadata>
                                        <ns:logo>https://hub-novaent-io-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/smooth/smoothmelbourne/logos/chromeCast/image.png</ns:logo>
                                    </ns:streamMetadata>
                                </ns:mediaMetadata>
                                <ns:mediaMetadata>
                                    <ns:id>79646630-4d88-4fcd-be20-d4d6a338db5f</ns:id>
                                    <ns:title>Smooth FM Brisbane</ns:title>
                                    <ns:mimeType>application/vnd.apple.mpegurl</ns:mimeType>
                                    <ns:itemType>stream</ns:itemType>
                                    <ns:summary>Brisbane's station for more music and less talk</ns:summary>
                                    <ns:streamMetadata>
                                        <ns:
                                    </ns:streamMetadata>
                                </ns:mediaMetadata>
                                <ns:mediaMetadata>
                                    <ns:id>87</ns:id>
                                    <ns:title>Smooth FM Adelaide</ns:title>
                                    <ns:mimeType>application/vnd.apple.mpegurl</ns:mimeType>
                                    <ns:itemType>stream</ns:itemType>
                                    <ns:summary>Adelaide's station for more music and less talk</ns:summary>
                                    <ns:streamMetadata>
                                        <ns:logo>
                                    </ns:streamMetadata>
                                </ns:mediaMetadata>
                                <ns:mediaMetadata>
                                    <ns:id>64</ns:id>
                                    <ns:title>Smooth FM Perth</ns:title>
                                    <ns:mimeType>application/vnd.apple.mpegurl</ns:mimeType>
                                    <ns:itemType>stream</ns:itemType>
                                    <ns:summary>Perth's station for more music and less talk</ns:summary>
                                    <ns:streamMetadata>
                                        <ns:logo></ns:logo>
                                    </ns:streamMetadata>
                                </ns:mediaMetadata>
                            </ns:getMetadataResult>
                        </ns:getMetadataResponse>
                    </soap:Body>
                </soap:Envelope>

I have added container in root with grid in sonos console but I'm not able to get the desired result
I am expecting to find an Header followed by list in horizontal scroll and then another header containing a list when scrolling horizontally
